# Es posible conectar un Frame creado en un JFrame, y como lograrlo?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, matisse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el palette  hay una opcion de `Frame` que crea una ventana dentro de otra ventana, sin embargo, no se como conectarlas atraves de un boton o si es que esto si se puede.
La ventana creada normamente con el `JFrame` form si aparece en el package,la otra no(la que se crea al usar el apartado `Frame` del palette).

Answer (score 1):

Para ponerle tamaño, yo casi siempre uso le método `pack` que se encarga de darle el mejor tamaño para los componentes que tenga dentro.

Así que agrego un action listener para hacerlo visible al click y lo pongo así:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jFrame1.pack();
    jFrame1.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Se verá algo así:

[image: frame agregado desde paleta a un JFrame form usando matisse]

EL código generaod queda algo así:

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions62843;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel1.setText("Frame2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(279, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(197, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel2.setText("Frame1");

        jButton1.setText("Mostrar JFrame2");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(130, 130, 130)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 158, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(148, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(145, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jFrame1.pack();
        jFrame1.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Como comentario final, los JFrames no son modales, así que estás haciendo una ventana totalmente independiente. Te recomiendo usar un JDialog en su lugar que te impedirá regresar a la ventana anterior hasta que no hayas hecho la acción que lo cierre (`dispose`).

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a la pregunta como conectarlas, estas son Jframes así que en el boton en el cual la quieras llamar solo tienen que poner:

```
NombreJframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: sucede que lo hago así y mi ventana (la que conecto) no aparece, me marca que en efecto esta activa pero en pantalla no se ve nada, es como si estuviese oculta o algo por el estilo, agradezco tu pronta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente porque no le has definido unn tamaño en tu constructor principal justo de bajo así:

```
initComponents();
NombreJframe.setSize(WIDTH, WIDTH);
```

y dentro le pones el tamaño que quieras.